# GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I have pasted the code from [microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/physicalmonitorenumerationapi/nf-physicalmonitorenumerationapi-getphysicalmonitorsfromhmonitor).
But when I run the program I have the errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR@8 referenced in function _main

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR@12 referenced in function _main

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DestroyPhysicalMonitors@8 referenced in function _main
```

How can I fix it? Help me, please!

Comment: this question is not duplicated. it asked what is static library of GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look in the documentation here:

> [GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/physicalmonitorenumerationapi/nf-physicalmonitorenumerationapi-getphysicalmonitorsfromhmonitor)

and locate this:

> Library... Dxva2.lib

In your C++ code you add somewhere:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")
```

And it pulls the library into linking process resolving the errors you quoted.

Comment: what is the static lib in mingw?